# Перемещение контента с помощью js тред второй.

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

И снова здравствуйте. Есть скрипт - http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/kKs8g/4/
Мне он нужен для того, что бы сделать быстрые ответы на комментарии.
Я ставил его на свой движок, но форма с комментариями показывается столько раз, сколько комментариев на странице. Что бы этого не было, мне посоветовали дать ID форме/кнопке открывающую форму.
В моем шаблоне с комментариями есть строчка php - `<?php echo $post['id']; ?>`, которая дает уникальный ID каждому комментарию.

```
<a class="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>
<div class="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">Здесь располагается форма"</div>
</div>
```

Тут все понятно, куда добавить, но как мне добавить `<?php echo $post['id']; ?>` в скрипт JQuery? Как не пробовал - не получилось.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `<?php echo $post['id']; ?>` не нужен в js, просто берите id родительского элемента при отправке комментария. сделайте fiddle с вашим сгенерённым контентом, чтобы было понятно как именно все выглядит на самом деле и что не работает.

Comment: Снова вы.  
http://rghost.ru/44385472
Вот, залил весь шаблон страницы, все откомментировал.

Comment: да не нужен  ваш php исходник, исходник страницы из браузера скопируйте и вставьтев jsfiddle

Comment: ага, еще бы сделать чтобы было больше одного коммета и кнопка показать/скрыть (это то что №?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hpF6C/1/  
Вот полностью вся страница, 3 комментария.  
Нет, там я ее вырезал. Вот тут эта кнопка такая же как в первом скрипте самого первого сообщения.

Comment: короче, я забью наверное, во первых я таки не понял таску, вам форму перемещать или что надо  ? судя по скрину это обычная борда, ваша задача помещать форму ответа к треду, чтобы типа на него ответить ?  кроме того у вас там куча ошибок  html, типа `<a class="var id = 292" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>`

Comment: Ладно. Да, форму.  
Да, борда.  
Да.  
Весь движок на костылях. Что поделать, десу.

Answer (score 1):

Хмм.

```
$(function(){
    var form = $('#postform');

    $('a.script-a').click(function(){ 
        form.insertAfter(  $(this).parents('table.post_table').eq(0) );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Если мне нужно было добавить этот код к тому, или заменить этим, то не работает.

Comment: У вас по ссылкам на код - чёрт ногу сломит, если честно. Обломаная вакаба наряду с непонятно какими-то подключаемыми скриптами, которые не могут подгрузится. Два раза загружается jquery. Вы в курсе, что хотите расположить одну форму внутри другой? Если не принципиально - возмите лучше кусабу.

Comment: >которые не могут подгрузится  
  
У всех все нормально работает.  
  
>возмите лучше кусабу.  
  
Очень смешно.

Comment: Вам уже столько советов надавали, а у вас всё никак не получается. Здесь за вас вашу работу никто делать не собирается. Посоветовать - это пожалуйста. Вот ещё один: 

> Успешное применение этих самых советов зависит от уровня вашего интеллекта.

Comment: Да. В этом файле содержится скрипт, который добавляет текст в форму по клику. Все работает, соснул?  
  
>Здесь за вас вашу работу никто делать не собирается.  
  
Да, конечно. Ведь так трудно заменить пару символов в коде.  
  
>Успешное применение этих самых советов зависит от уровня знания языков программирования.  
  
Исправил, не благодари.

Comment: Откуда вы такие лезите?...